# Manifest fetch failed (9)

Tags: google-chrome, html5-appcache, cache-manifest, application-cache

I've been working with Appcache for quite some time, but I recently took a couple of weeks to develop a different project.  When I returned to my offline project, I started getting this error every time I try to download the contents of my manifest:
Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (9)
This is followed by 2 addresses; the file and line number of the page that calls the manifest (on right of same line), and the relative url of the manifest itself (on a second line).  The download of the individual resources does not begin.

Now, other folks work on this project, but I'm the only guy who touches anything that as much as smells of offline.  The issue doesn't appear to be related to any of my usual suspects, like a syntax error in the manifest (tried clearing all the files, just to be sure), the manifest being served incorrectly, or something wrong with one of the files being cached.  I don't think it's a memory problem, as I have over 30 gigs of space outside of the size of the files I'm caching.  Furthermore, this worked 2 weeks ago, so I'm assuming that there isn't something wrong with my setup.  However, nobody seems to know what the hell this error is; nobody even seems to be getting this error.  I can't find anything online to describe what this issue is.  Hence, my question is:

What does Manifest fetch Failed (9) mean?

My browser is Chrome on Windows 7, and is up to date.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: My other offline projects still function on chrome, so mystery problem continues to be a mystery

Answer (score 26):

GAH.  Ok so I figured out the problem, or at least I figured out a solution.  9 *might* indicate a certificate error, which is what I was experiencing.  Lovely, just... lovely.

Comment: ARgggh thanks! Had the same issues using a self signed certificate.. doh! Annoying

Comment: did you end up with a solution?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying out some offline stuff on a test site and ran into this certificate problem. I just removed the certificate on the test site.

Comment: The same at here. @gonzofish you can set yourself the domain to local IP address, so the true certificate will accomplish it w/o problem. Or... you can simply remove the certificate at localhost.

Comment: I have the same trouble, i'm working on a real server not localhost and only appCache fails on HTTPS. How do you fix it?

Comment: Is it any way to fix this problem for self-signed certificates without running chrome with --ignore-certicate-errors?

Answer (score 12):

`(9)` means that there is a security error. Since cache manifests with invalid certificates allow a man-in-the-middle attack, as explained in [the Chromium issue that disallowed this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=414026). If you still want to use a cache manifest with an invalid certificate for testing purposes, you can pass `--ignore-certicate-errors` to Chrome on launch.

Comment: "--ignore-certicate-errors" not working with chrome 70.0.3538.77